# floor modulo or modulo rounding towards negative infinity

Tags: c++, performance, c

The first function will always try to correct the final result, while the second uses a conditional to know when to compensate. I think that in general the second function will be faster, but it will look a little worse than the first.

```c
int floor_mod1(int a, int b)
{
    int mod = a % b;
    return (mod + b) % b;
}

int floor_mod2(int a, int b)
{
    int mod = a % b;
    if (mod != 0 && (a ^ b) < 0) {
        return mod + b;
    }
    return mod;
}
```

What does the condition do?
There's not need to correct already calculated `0` to `0`, so we will not do anything in case when `mod == 0`. If `a` and `b` have the same sign, we will not anything, because the result is already correct.

---

More details:
And in fact, we can use `(mod ^ b) < 0` instead of `(a ^ b) < 0` to work with the old version of the language, where the modulo operator could round towards either zero or negative infinity.

Moreover, we can replace `mod != 0` with `(mod ^ b) != b` (not with `(a ^ b) != b`), but this will probably slow down our code, it depends on the compiler.
BUT, if someone can figure out how to replace these parts (`(mod ^ b) != b  && (mod ^ b) < 0`...) with fewer operations, then such implementation will probably be the best one. (keep in mind the most important facts: `b` will never be equal to `0`, for the condition to work `a` and `b` must have different signs and `a` should not be equal to `0`)

.. and we could probably write a better version in assembly, but it won't be as portable ..

---

Should I return value here `return mod + b;` or use `mod += b`?
Should I choose the second version because of its speed, regardless of the not-so-pretty code?
Am I correct that using `(mod ^ b) < 0` instead of `(a ^ b) < 0` doesn't matter for performance?
Any other comments?

Comment: Personally I prefer the first version which - at least for me - is easier to read. If you one day notice that you have a performance issue in the function you can take a look at it again. Always try to write code that is easy to read, the future you and any colleagues will thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Broken corner cases**

"The first function will always try to correct the final result, " is unsupported, due to undefined behavior, when `mod + b` overflows as in `floor_mod1(1, INT_MAX)`.

> I think that in general the second function will be faster,

Speed should be a secondary concern, get the function to work correctly for all `int a`, `int b`.

---

**Make code functionally correct before spending much effort on speed.**

Sample functional test harness that exhibits functional problems

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int floor_mod1(int a, int b) {
  int mod = a % b;
  return (mod + b) % b;
}

int floor_mod2(int a, int b) {
  int mod = a % b;
  if (mod != 0 && (a ^ b) < 0) {
    return mod + b;
  }
  return mod;
}

// Wider math for reference
int floor_modR(int a, int b) {
  long long mod = (1LL * a) % b;
  return (int) ((mod + b) % b);
}

int main() {
  const int t[] = {0, 1, 2, 42, INT_MAX - 1, INT_MAX, -1, -2, INT_MIN + 1,
      INT_MIN};
  size_t n = sizeof t / sizeof t[0];
  for (size_t ia = 0; ia < n; ia++) {
    int a = t[ia];
    for (size_t ib = 0; ib < n; ib++) {
      int b = t[ib];
      if (b == 0) {
        continue;
      }
      // Better floor_mod() would handle this case too 
      // Both  floor_mod1(), floor_mod2() fail this case.
      if (a == INT_MIN && b == -1) {
        continue;
      }
      int m1 = floor_mod1(a, b);
      int m2 = floor_mod2(a, b);
      int mR = floor_modR(a, b);
      if (m1 != mR || m2 != mR) {
        printf("f(%d,%d) --> %d %d %d\n", a, b, m1, m2, mR);
        fflush(stdout);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
f(1,2147483647) --> -1 1 1
f(2,2147483646) --> -2 2 2
f(2,2147483647) --> 0 2 2
f(42,2147483646) --> -2147483608 42 42
f(42,2147483647) --> -2147483607 42 42
f(2147483646,2147483647) --> -3 2147483646 2147483646
f(-1,-2147483648) --> 2147483647 -1 -1
f(-2,-2147483647) --> 0 -2 -2
f(-2,-2147483648) --> 2147483646 -2 -2
f(-2147483647,-2147483648) --> 1 -2147483647 -2147483647
```

Comment: All `floor_mod`s will return `0` in case of `a == INT_MIN && b == -1`, aren't they? Perhaps it is, as @Quuxplusone said, implementation-defined behavior of `(a ^ b)`. Did you tried functionally identical version with `(a < 0) != (b < 0)` instead?

Comment: @0dminnimda `a%b` is only defined when `a/b` is defined.  Since the quotient `INT_MIN/-1` attempts a quotient more than `INT_MAX`, `INT_MIN%-1` is _undefined behavior_ (UB).  I did not try `(a < 0) != (b < 0)`.  Easy enough for anyone to try.

Comment: well, it looks like `INT_MIN % -1` itself is implementation-defined behavior, because with another compiler this results in a failure.

Comment: `I did not try (a < 0) != (b < 0). Easy enough for anyone to try.` this does not change anything.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica probably some of the code of [this :) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30400252/12141949) will help here. This seems to be a pretty fitting addition. What do you think? :>

Comment: although it is rather unlikely that such values will be passed to the function.

Comment: @0dminnimda "INT_MIN % -1 itself is implementation-defined behavior" --> it is UB. "The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined." C17dr § 6.5.5 5.  Ture that a given implementation may define a result, but it is free to leave it as UB and do whatever.

Comment: @0dminnimda "unlikely that such values will be passed to the function" is an interesting defense.  Intel [tried the 1 in 9 billion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug) augment.  Cost $400+ million.,  Your call.  As I try to emphasize, make certain the function is correct, then [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature) optimize.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica well, definitely I was checking some small values ​​and it seemed to me that the implementation was correct, just forgot about over/underflow.  In any case, I cannot leave undefined behaviour here, it must always match the mathematical model, so this check will eventually end up in the implementation.

Comment: Well, you made the biggest impact on the end result, although the other answer is pretty good too. Therefore, I accept your answer as the most helpful!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1cKbnqr3n) to play around with the C code and see if anything makes the assembly look particularly better. (Seems like Clang is strangely much better than GCC at making this code branch-free.)

*Technically*, `(a ^ b)` has implementation-defined behavior if you end up XORing non-zero sign bit(s) together. It's better (in terms of portability) to write `(a < 0) != (b < 0)`. Let the compiler figure out the bit-twiddling.

Anyway, you're assuming that this function needs optimization... you've profiled your program and seen that it's the hot spot? So you're trying to turn two `idiv` instructions into one `idiv` instruction? Have you looked at your program's workload? Maybe you could even turn that one `idiv` into no `idiv`s... on the happy path.

This exact situation is covered in Chandler Carruth's ["Tuning C++"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk) from CppCon 2015. He replaces `o = i % ceil;` with `o = (i >= ceil) ? i % ceil : i;` and the code magically gets faster. Consider whether your hot spot would benefit from similar workload analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much for the good answer, the other answer had a greater impact on the result, no offense to you, but I accept it.

Comment: Quuxplusone, OP's code use `int`.  `o = i % ceil;` functions differently from `o = (i >= ceil) ? i % ceil : i;` when `cell > 0, i  < -cell`.  If full range `i, cell` is important, getting faster is not worth the coding error.